# the slash value of $_GET variable changes to underbar in IE

Tags: php, get

When I pass the variable as below..

```
var file_path = "/admin/upload/rec1.20130522_003928.f4v";
...
ifrm.src = download.php?file_path=" + file_path;
```

It shows the link as

> _admin_upload_rec1.20130522_003928.f4v

(Capture: http://screencast.com/t/ooQHLdr5cixz)

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, in the script where you send the file, you are also sending a [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) header that tells the browser that this is a download, not a resource to try and show immediately.  I'd presume you're also sending `$_GET['file_path']` as the filename in that header.

When you send that header, don't include the directory part.  Browsers will do whatever they want with the directory part, from stripping it off to mangling it.  Pretty much the only thing they won't do (for security reasons) is actually use it as a directory name.

You can send the base filename using something like

```
$path_parts = preg_split(':[/\\]+:', $_GET['file_path']);
$filename = addslashes(end($path_parts));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much! I have a idea from you. ^^

And Could you provide for me the better solution for using [Content-Disposition]?

Comment: @JaeHunDanielHwang: Just split on slashes and backslashes, and take the last part of the array you get back.  Edited to include an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed from ':[/\\]+:' to ':[\\/]+:'.
It works good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `var file_path = "\admin\upload\rec1.20130522_003928.f4v"; ... ifrm.src = download.php?file_path=" + file_path;` instead.

Comment: Windows is fine with forward slashes.  It converts them to backslashes behind the scenes.  If this is the issue, then IE is doing something very odd even by IE standards.

Comment: BTW, the backslashes need escaping.